# How to terminate Jquery setIntereval?

Tags: jquery, setinterval, terminate

I am trying to terminate setIntreval that refresh my page. But cleareIntreval() not work for me.

I have

```
 $chatInterval = setInterval(function(){
$.post('user/home/show_conversation.php',{ f_id : userID},function(ajaxCevap){

        $('#chatbox').html(ajaxCevap);
        $('#chatbox').scrollTop = $('#chatbox').scrollHeight;

    });

},10000);
```

And when I click button I use   `clearInterval($chatInterval);`  But is says that $chatInterval not defined. yes Those are in different function scope.How can I declare common variable setInterval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it deleting  $ element from

```
    chatInterval = setInterval(function(){
$.post('user/home/show_conversation.php',{ f_id : userID},function(ajaxCevap){

        $('#chatbox').html(ajaxCevap);
        $('#chatbox').scrollTop = $('#chatbox').scrollHeight;

    });

},10000);
```

Now I can call it in any function.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo there, and make sure the variable you created `$chatInterval` is in the scope of the location you call `clearInterval()` from.

```
clearInterval($chatInterval);
```

If you need to declare the variable in a scope accessible to both, either declare it at the top-level or store it on an element somewhere using the `.data()` method of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/data/